# Google App Script to Execute A Function based on Column Value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute different functions based on the value of my columns. I have 3 values that as a reference for the function. below are my codes:

```
function GenerateFinalReport(){
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange("AF:AF").getValue 
== "Corinthians"){
   GenerateCorReport();
   }
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange("AF:AF").getValue 
== "MCT"){
   GenerateMCTReport();
   }
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange("AF:AF").getValue 
== "PSG"){
  GeneratePSGReport();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running into some issue ? If yes, pls share the error.

Comment: It runs but does not execute the functions that I called as per the column values. There's no error message though.